# Yarn Build Fails on the esbiuild

Tags: javascript, node.js, cmd, yarnpkg, esbuild

The project I'm working on uses Yarn and I am new to it but having some teething issues. The project runs but the js does not.

1. I installed Node.js (v16.9.0) and Yarn globally.
2. I pulled the repo and from the command I navigate to the project path and did `yarn install`;
   which runs fine.

   - Yarn (v2.4.0-git.20210112.hash-8eba2920)

Here are the list of yarn commands I can use

```
➤ YN0000: build:css     'yarn postcss assets/css/site.css -o wwwroot/css/site.css'
➤ YN0000: build:js      'node build.js'
➤ YN0000: build         'yarn run-p build:css build:js'
➤ YN0000: publish:css   'yarn cross-env NODE_ENV=production yarn postcss assets/css/site.css -o wwwroot/css/site.css'
➤ YN0000: publish:js    'yarn cross-env NODE_ENV=production node build.js'
➤ YN0000: publish       'yarn cross-env NODE_ENV=production yarn run-p publish:css publish:js'
➤ YN0000: stackup       '../../scripts/dev/start_mssql_container.sh && dotnet watch run'
➤ YN0000: watch         'yarn npm-watch'
➤ YN0000: Done in 0s 3ms
```

When I try to do a `yarn build` it give me the following. Is it an issue with the node setup? or is it a yarn issue?

I've tried to search for this issue but my best guess so far is the esbuild is not right but not sure how to fix.

```
 > .yarn/$$virtual/esbuild-plugin-pnp-virtual-b0ebe0e05a/0/cache/esbuild-plugin-pnp-npm-0.3.0-c8f5fdc52d-b80ab17bea.zip/node_modules/esbuild-plugin-pnp/index.js:32:50: error: [pnp-plugin] Cannot read properties of null (reading '1')
    32 │         let resolveDir = args.path.match(/(.+\/)/)[1];
       ╵                                                   ^
    at C:\Development\Project\src\Project.Web\.yarn\$$virtual\esbuild-plugin-pnp-virtual-b0ebe0e05a\0\cache\esbuild-plugin-pnp-npm-0.3.0-c8f5fdc52d-b80ab17bea.zip\node_modules\esbuild-plugin-pnp\index.js:32:51
    at callback (C:\Development\Project\src\Project.Web\.yarn\unplugged\esbuild-npm-0.8.57-7fe43e451a\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:744:34)

   .yarn/$$virtual/esbuild-plugin-pnp-virtual-b0ebe0e05a/0/cache/esbuild-plugin-pnp-npm-0.3.0-c8f5fdc52d-b80ab17bea.zip/node_modules/esbuild-plugin-pnp/index.js:31:12: note: This error came from the "onLoad" callback registered here
    31 │       build.onLoad({ filter: /.*/, namespace: "pnp" }, async args => {
       ╵             ~~~~~~
    at setup (C:\Development\Project\src\Project.Web\.yarn\$$virtual\esbuild-plugin-pnp-virtual-b0ebe0e05a\0\cache\esbuild-plugin-pnp-npm-0.3.0-c8f5fdc52d-b80ab17bea.zip\node_modules\esbuild-plugin-pnp\index.js:31:13)
    at handlePlugins (C:\Development\Project\src\Project.Web\.yarn\unplugged\esbuild-npm-0.8.57-7fe43e451a\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:659:7)

 > .yarn/$$virtual/esbuild-plugin-pnp-virtual-b0ebe0e05a/0/cache/esbuild-plugin-pnp-npm-0.3.0-c8f5fdc52d-b80ab17bea.zip/node_modules/esbuild-plugin-pnp/index.js:32:50: error: [pnp-plugin] Cannot read properties of null (reading '1')
    32 │         let resolveDir = args.path.match(/(.+\/)/)[1];
       ╵                                                   ^
    at C:\Development\Project\src\Project.Web\.yarn\$$virtual\esbuild-plugin-pnp-virtual-b0ebe0e05a\0\cache\esbuild-plugin-pnp-npm-0.3.0-c8f5fdc52d-b80ab17bea.zip\node_modules\esbuild-plugin-pnp\index.js:32:51
    at callback (C:\Development\Project\src\Project.Web\.yarn\unplugged\esbuild-npm-0.8.57-7fe43e451a\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:744:34)

   .yarn/$$virtual/esbuild-plugin-pnp-virtual-b0ebe0e05a/0/cache/esbuild-plugin-pnp-npm-0.3.0-c8f5fdc52d-b80ab17bea.zip/node_modules/esbuild-plugin-pnp/index.js:31:12: note: This error came from the "onLoad" callback registered here
    31 │       build.onLoad({ filter: /.*/, namespace: "pnp" }, async args => {
       ╵             ~~~~~~
    at setup (C:\Development\Project\src\Project.Web\.yarn\$$virtual\esbuild-plugin-pnp-virtual-b0ebe0e05a\0\cache\esbuild-plugin-pnp-npm-0.3.0-c8f5fdc52d-b80ab17bea.zip\node_modules\esbuild-plugin-pnp\index.js:31:13)
    at handlePlugins (C:\Development\Project\src\Project.Web\.yarn\unplugged\esbuild-npm-0.8.57-7fe43e451a\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:659:7)

 > .yarn/$$virtual/esbuild-plugin-pnp-virtual-b0ebe0e05a/0/cache/esbuild-plugin-pnp-npm-0.3.0-c8f5fdc52d-b80ab17bea.zip/node_modules/esbuild-plugin-pnp/index.js:32:50: error: [pnp-plugin] Cannot read properties of null (reading '1')
    32 │         let resolveDir = args.path.match(/(.+\/)/)[1];
       ╵                                                   ^
    at C:\Development\Project\src\Project.Web\.yarn\$$virtual\esbuild-plugin-pnp-virtual-b0ebe0e05a\0\cache\esbuild-plugin-pnp-npm-0.3.0-c8f5fdc52d-b80ab17bea.zip\node_modules\esbuild-plugin-pnp\index.js:32:51
    at callback (C:\Development\Project\src\Project.Web\.yarn\unplugged\esbuild-npm-0.8.57-7fe43e451a\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:744:34)

   .yarn/$$virtual/esbuild-plugin-pnp-virtual-b0ebe0e05a/0/cache/esbuild-plugin-pnp-npm-0.3.0-c8f5fdc52d-b80ab17bea.zip/node_modules/esbuild-plugin-pnp/index.js:31:12: note: This error came from the "onLoad" callback registered here
    31 │       build.onLoad({ filter: /.*/, namespace: "pnp" }, async args => {
       ╵             ~~~~~~
    at setup (C:\Development\Project\src\Project.Web\.yarn\$$virtual\esbuild-plugin-pnp-virtual-b0ebe0e05a\0\cache\esbuild-plugin-pnp-npm-0.3.0-c8f5fdc52d-b80ab17bea.zip\node_modules\esbuild-plugin-pnp\index.js:31:13)
    at handlePlugins (C:\Development\Project\src\Project.Web\.yarn\unplugged\esbuild-npm-0.8.57-7fe43e451a\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:659:7)

 > .yarn/$$virtual/esbuild-plugin-pnp-virtual-b0ebe0e05a/0/cache/esbuild-plugin-pnp-npm-0.3.0-c8f5fdc52d-b80ab17bea.zip/node_modules/esbuild-plugin-pnp/index.js:32:50: error: [pnp-plugin] Cannot read properties of null (reading '1')
    32 │         let resolveDir = args.path.match(/(.+\/)/)[1];
       ╵                                                   ^
    at C:\Development\Project\src\Project.Web\.yarn\$$virtual\esbuild-plugin-pnp-virtual-b0ebe0e05a\0\cache\esbuild-plugin-pnp-npm-0.3.0-c8f5fdc52d-b80ab17bea.zip\node_modules\esbuild-plugin-pnp\index.js:32:51
    at callback (C:\Development\Project\src\Project.Web\.yarn\unplugged\esbuild-npm-0.8.57-7fe43e451a\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:744:34)

   .yarn/$$virtual/esbuild-plugin-pnp-virtual-b0ebe0e05a/0/cache/esbuild-plugin-pnp-npm-0.3.0-c8f5fdc52d-b80ab17bea.zip/node_modules/esbuild-plugin-pnp/index.js:31:12: note: This error came from the "onLoad" callback registered here
    31 │       build.onLoad({ filter: /.*/, namespace: "pnp" }, async args => {
       ╵             ~~~~~~
    at setup (C:\Development\Project\src\Project.Web\.yarn\$$virtual\esbuild-plugin-pnp-virtual-b0ebe0e05a\0\cache\esbuild-plugin-pnp-npm-0.3.0-c8f5fdc52d-b80ab17bea.zip\node_modules\esbuild-plugin-pnp\index.js:31:13)
    at handlePlugins (C:\Development\Project\src\Project.Web\.yarn\unplugged\esbuild-npm-0.8.57-7fe43e451a\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:659:7)

 > .yarn/$$virtual/esbuild-plugin-pnp-virtual-b0ebe0e05a/0/cache/esbuild-plugin-pnp-npm-0.3.0-c8f5fdc52d-b80ab17bea.zip/node_modules/esbuild-plugin-pnp/index.js:32:50: error: [pnp-plugin] Cannot read properties of null (reading '1')
    32 │         let resolveDir = args.path.match(/(.+\/)/)[1];
       ╵                                                   ^
    at C:\Development\Project\src\Project.Web\.yarn\$$virtual\esbuild-plugin-pnp-virtual-b0ebe0e05a\0\cache\esbuild-plugin-pnp-npm-0.3.0-c8f5fdc52d-b80ab17bea.zip\node_modules\esbuild-plugin-pnp\index.js:32:51
    at callback (C:\Development\Project\src\Project.Web\.yarn\unplugged\esbuild-npm-0.8.57-7fe43e451a\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:744:34)

   .yarn/$$virtual/esbuild-plugin-pnp-virtual-b0ebe0e05a/0/cache/esbuild-plugin-pnp-npm-0.3.0-c8f5fdc52d-b80ab17bea.zip/node_modules/esbuild-plugin-pnp/index.js:31:12: note: This error came from the "onLoad" callback registered here
    31 │       build.onLoad({ filter: /.*/, namespace: "pnp" }, async args => {
       ╵             ~~~~~~
    at setup (C:\Development\Project\src\Project.Web\.yarn\$$virtual\esbuild-plugin-pnp-virtual-b0ebe0e05a\0\cache\esbuild-plugin-pnp-npm-0.3.0-c8f5fdc52d-b80ab17bea.zip\node_modules\esbuild-plugin-pnp\index.js:31:13)
    at handlePlugins (C:\Development\Project\src\Project.Web\.yarn\unplugged\esbuild-npm-0.8.57-7fe43e451a\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:659:7)

5 errors
Error: Build failed with 5 errors:
.yarn/$$virtual/esbuild-plugin-pnp-virtual-b0ebe0e05a/0/cache/esbuild-plugin-pnp-npm-0.3.0-c8f5fdc52d-b80ab17bea.zip/node_modules/esbuild-plugin-pnp/index.js:32:50: error: [pnp-plugin] Cannot read properties of null (reading '1')
.yarn/$$virtual/esbuild-plugin-pnp-virtual-b0ebe0e05a/0/cache/esbuild-plugin-pnp-npm-0.3.0-c8f5fdc52d-b80ab17bea.zip/node_modules/esbuild-plugin-pnp/index.js:32:50: error: [pnp-plugin] Cannot read properties of null (reading '1')
.yarn/$$virtual/esbuild-plugin-pnp-virtual-b0ebe0e05a/0/cache/esbuild-plugin-pnp-npm-0.3.0-c8f5fdc52d-b80ab17bea.zip/node_modules/esbuild-plugin-pnp/index.js:32:50: error: [pnp-plugin] Cannot read properties of null (reading '1')
.yarn/$$virtual/esbuild-plugin-pnp-virtual-b0ebe0e05a/0/cache/esbuild-plugin-pnp-npm-0.3.0-c8f5fdc52d-b80ab17bea.zip/node_modules/esbuild-plugin-pnp/index.js:32:50: error: [pnp-plugin] Cannot read properties of null (reading '1')
.yarn/$$virtual/esbuild-plugin-pnp-virtual-b0ebe0e05a/0/cache/esbuild-plugin-pnp-npm-0.3.0-c8f5fdc52d-b80ab17bea.zip/node_modules/esbuild-plugin-pnp/index.js:32:50: error: [pnp-plugin] Cannot read properties of null (reading '1')
    at failureErrorWithLog (C:\Development\Project\src\Project.Web\.yarn\unplugged\esbuild-npm-0.8.57-7fe43e451a\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:1160:15)
    at buildResponseToResult (C:\Development\Project\src\Project.Web\.yarn\unplugged\esbuild-npm-0.8.57-7fe43e451a\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:896:32)
    at C:\Development\Project\src\Project.Web\.yarn\unplugged\esbuild-npm-0.8.57-7fe43e451a\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:991:20
    at C:\Development\Project\src\Project.Web\.yarn\unplugged\esbuild-npm-0.8.57-7fe43e451a\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:542:9
    at handleIncomingPacket (C:\Development\Project\src\Project.Web\.yarn\unplugged\esbuild-npm-0.8.57-7fe43e451a\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:631:9)
    at Socket.readFromStdout (C:\Development\Project\src\Project.Web\.yarn\unplugged\esbuild-npm-0.8.57-7fe43e451a\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:509:7)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:394:28)
    at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:315:12)
    at readableAddChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:289:9)
    at Socket.Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:228:10) {
  errors: [
    {
      detail: TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading '1')
          at C:\Development\Project\src\Project.Web\.yarn\$$virtual\esbuild-plugin-pnp-virtual-b0ebe0e05a\0\cache\esbuild-plugin-pnp-npm-0.3.0-c8f5fdc52d-b80ab17bea.zip\node_modules\esbuild-plugin-pnp\index.js:32:51
          at callback (C:\Development\Project\src\Project.Web\.yarn\unplugged\esbuild-npm-0.8.57-7fe43e451a\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:744:34)
          at handleRequest (C:\Development\Project\src\Project.Web\.yarn\unplugged\esbuild-npm-0.8.57-7fe43e451a\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:577:36)
          at handleIncomingPacket (C:\Development\Project\src\Project.Web\.yarn\unplugged\esbuild-npm-0.8.57-7fe43e451a\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:624:7)
          at Socket.readFromStdout (C:\Development\Project\src\Project.Web\.yarn\unplugged\esbuild-npm-0.8.57-7fe43e451a\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:509:7)
          at Socket.emit (node:events:394:28)
          at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:315:12)
          at readableAddChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:289:9)
          at Socket.Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:228:10)
          at Pipe.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:199:23),
      location: [Object],
      notes: [Array],
      text: "[pnp-plugin] Cannot read properties of null (reading '1')"
    },
    {
      detail: TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading '1')
          at C:\Development\Project\src\Project.Web\.yarn\$$virtual\esbuild-plugin-pnp-virtual-b0ebe0e05a\0\cache\esbuild-plugin-pnp-npm-0.3.0-c8f5fdc52d-b80ab17bea.zip\node_modules\esbuild-plugin-pnp\index.js:32:51
          at callback (C:\Development\Project\src\Project.Web\.yarn\unplugged\esbuild-npm-0.8.57-7fe43e451a\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:744:34)
          at handleRequest (C:\Development\Project\src\Project.Web\.yarn\unplugged\esbuild-npm-0.8.57-7fe43e451a\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:577:36)
          at handleIncomingPacket (C:\Development\Project\src\Project.Web\.yarn\unplugged\esbuild-npm-0.8.57-7fe43e451a\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:624:7)
          at Socket.readFromStdout (C:\Development\Project\src\Project.Web\.yarn\unplugged\esbuild-npm-0.8.57-7fe43e451a\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:509:7)
          at Socket.emit (node:events:394:28)
          at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:315:12)
          at readableAddChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:289:9)
          at Socket.Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:228:10)
          at Pipe.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:199:23),
      location: [Object],
      notes: [Array],
      text: "[pnp-plugin] Cannot read properties of null (reading '1')"
    },
    {
      detail: TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading '1')
          at C:\Development\Project\src\Project.Web\.yarn\$$virtual\esbuild-plugin-pnp-virtual-b0ebe0e05a\0\cache\esbuild-plugin-pnp-npm-0.3.0-c8f5fdc52d-b80ab17bea.zip\node_modules\esbuild-plugin-pnp\index.js:32:51
          at callback (C:\Development\Project\src\Project.Web\.yarn\unplugged\esbuild-npm-0.8.57-7fe43e451a\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:744:34)
          at handleRequest (C:\Development\Project\src\Project.Web\.yarn\unplugged\esbuild-npm-0.8.57-7fe43e451a\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:577:36)
          at handleIncomingPacket (C:\Development\Project\src\Fixie.Web\.yarn\unplugged\esbuild-npm-0.8.57-7fe43e451a\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:624:7)
          at Socket.readFromStdout (C:\Development\Fixie\src\Project.Web\.yarn\unplugged\esbuild-npm-0.8.57-7fe43e451a\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:509:7)
          at Socket.emit (node:events:394:28)
          at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:315:12)
          at readableAddChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:289:9)
          at Socket.Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:228:10)
          at Pipe.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:199:23),
      location: [Object],
      notes: [Array],
      text: "[pnp-plugin] Cannot read properties of null (reading '1')"
    },
    {
      detail: TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading '1')
          at C:\Development\Project\src\Project.Web\.yarn\$$virtual\esbuild-plugin-pnp-virtual-b0ebe0e05a\0\cache\esbuild-plugin-pnp-npm-0.3.0-c8f5fdc52d-b80ab17bea.zip\node_modules\esbuild-plugin-pnp\index.js:32:51
          at callback (C:\Development\Project\src\Project.Web\.yarn\unplugged\esbuild-npm-0.8.57-7fe43e451a\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:744:34)
          at handleRequest (C:\Development\Project\src\Project.Web\.yarn\unplugged\esbuild-npm-0.8.57-7fe43e451a\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:577:36)
          at handleIncomingPacket (C:\Development\Project\src\Project.Web\.yarn\unplugged\esbuild-npm-0.8.57-7fe43e451a\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:624:7)
          at Socket.readFromStdout (C:\Development\Project\src\Project.Web\.yarn\unplugged\esbuild-npm-0.8.57-7fe43e451a\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:509:7)
          at Socket.emit (node:events:394:28)
          at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:315:12)
          at readableAddChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:289:9)
          at Socket.Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:228:10)
          at Pipe.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:199:23),
      location: [Object],
      notes: [Array],
      text: "[pnp-plugin] Cannot read properties of null (reading '1')"
    },
    {
      detail: TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading '1')
          at C:\Development\Project\src\Project.Web\.yarn\$$virtual\esbuild-plugin-pnp-virtual-b0ebe0e05a\0\cache\esbuild-plugin-pnp-npm-0.3.0-c8f5fdc52d-b80ab17bea.zip\node_modules\esbuild-plugin-pnp\index.js:32:51
          at callback (C:\Development\Project\src\Project.Web\.yarn\unplugged\esbuild-npm-0.8.57-7fe43e451a\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:744:34)
          at handleRequest (C:\Development\Project\src\Project.Web\.yarn\unplugged\esbuild-npm-0.8.57-7fe43e451a\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:577:36)
          at handleIncomingPacket (C:\Development\Project\src\Project.Web\.yarn\unplugged\esbuild-npm-0.8.57-7fe43e451a\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:624:7)
          at Socket.readFromStdout (C:\Development\Project\src\Project.Web\.yarn\unplugged\esbuild-npm-0.8.57-7fe43e451a\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:509:7)
          at Socket.emit (node:events:394:28)
          at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:315:12)
          at readableAddChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:289:9)
          at Socket.Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:228:10)
          at Pipe.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:199:23),
      location: [Object],
      notes: [Array],
      text: "[pnp-plugin] Cannot read properties of null (reading '1')"
    }
  ],
  warnings: []
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Update I have now resolved this.

After the yarn install do the following commands,

yarn add @yarnpkg/esbuild-plugin-pnp

then inside build.js replace line 2 with
`const pnpPlugin = require('esbuild-plugin-pnp');`

then do yarn add esbuild -D

then yarn build should work.